# How to interpret the %cpu of wa (waiting) percentage?

Tags: cpu

Given results from top commands:

```bsh
top - 10:21:11 up 124 days, 14:40,  5 users,  load average: 124.16, 59.37, 31.47
Tasks: 580 total,   4 running, 576 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7.8 us,  1.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 42.2 id, 47.8 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 26385592+total,   741432 free, 56779316 used, 20633516+buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4194300 total,        0 free,  4194300 used. 20564470+avail Mem
```

Do I get 42% idle pct of CPU to explore or 42.2+47.8 (id + wa) = 80%+ cpu resource to use?

Answer (score -1):

Do a man tab to see the manpage.   There I found:

> %CPU  --  CPU usage
>             The  task's  share  of  the  elapsed CPU time since the last screen update, expressed as a percentage of total CPU time.  In a true
>   SMP environment, if 'Irix
>             mode' is Off, top will operate in 'Solaris mode' where a task's cpu usage will be divided by the total number of CPUs.  You
>   toggle 'Irix/Solaris' modes  with
>             the 'I' interactive command.